# user-agent string for url bot

Tags: c#, web-crawler, user-agent, bots

Hello I am trying to create a simple bot that retrieves the contents of webpages. I am very knew to this process. My end goal is to have an app that can retrieve information on food products by looking them up on the web. This simple code I have here is just supposed to go to a webpage and print out the source code for the page, but I keep getting redirected because " user-agent string appears to be from an automated process". Well of course its from an automated process...Am I missing something here? How do I format my user-agent string to be acceptable out in the web? Or do I need to approach this totally differently? Do you have to be special to have a webcrawler now?

```
 try
 {
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

     client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 25600;
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     Console.WriteLine(responsebody);
 }
 catch (HttpRequestException e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
 }
```

Comment: If a web site doesn't allow automated processes (web crawlers) to access their data, we as developers should respect that. Usually, information about which parts of a web site you can access with a web scraper can be found in robots.txt (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt). If the page you are retrieving is listed with Disallow in front of it, that's basically the web site's way of telling you not to access that page with a web scraper.

Answer (score -1):

You can change `user-agent` header to make your program fake a browser. For example IE 10:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
```